# How to disable coverage of a sub-block when using `-COVERAGE a -COVDut`

Tags: code-coverage, specman, e

I am working on a design that has a hierarchy that looks like this:

- Top_level_block

  o    Sub_block_1

  .....

  o    Sub_block_6

  o    Sub_block_7

I use the elaboration options in ncelab to enable the coverage for the top_level_block:

```
-COVERAGE a -COVDut top_level_block
```

This enables the coverage on the top_level_block and all of its sub_blocks as well. Now I would like to disable coverage of the sub_block_6 and sub_block_7 only. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of coverage are you talking about? `-covdut` handles code coverage.

Comment: @Tudor Yes, code coverage is what I am looking for. I think the solution may be in using 'deselect_coverage'. But I am not sure exactly.

Comment: Yeah, you're on the right track. Unfortunately, I can't say what the exact syntax is. You'll have to look it up in the manual, but as I remember it's pretty well explained. Try it out and if you don't solve it I'll dig out some old project and look there. BTW, this question isn't Specman related, it's an ncelab thing (as the elaborator handles code coverage).

Comment: @Tudor I don't think there is a tag for ncelab and I don't have the reputation to create one. Feel free to add the tag f you can. This is where I am right now:                                     % ncelab -covdut Top_level_block -covfile cov.ccf  ( + some other options.)   And in my cov. cff I have something that looks like:                                  deselect_coverage -block -sub_block7                                                But now I am getting the following error. "Cannot open instrumentation configuration file cov.ccf". I did made sure to put my ccf file in my lib directory.

Comment: The file has to be in your CWD. Use a relative/absolute path otherwise.